# Android sensor update rate

Tags: android

I have been working on Android sensors and I can't confirm when the onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) actually fires.

1)I started the sensorListener

2)I assumed onSensorChanged fired when the sensor changed from its previous value (stored where???)

3)I ended the listener (after 60 seconds)

I repeated the same steps 5 minutes later with no phone changes and I get a few different values and a whole bunch of zeroes.

Can someone point to somewhere in the documentation that answers this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onSensorChanged is called if new sensor values can be taken. Specifically you can set the frequency of getting sensor values:

> android.hardware.SensorManager.registerListener(SensorListener 
>   listener, int sensors, int rate)
>
> int        SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST        get sensor data as fast as
>   possible
>
> int        SENSOR_DELAY_GAME        rate suitable for games
>
> int        SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL        rate (default) suitable for
>   screen orientation changes
>
> int        SENSOR_DELAY_UI        rate suitable for the user interface